# heroku retain files/folders while re-deploying new version of nodejs application to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, deployment, web-deployment

My folder structure for images looks like below

```
./public/img/**
```

under img folder I have following folders - categoryImages, languageImages, socialShareImages and userImages.
Now I want to retain the userImages as this contains images uploaded by user, But every time I deploy a new version of my app to heroku with "git push heroku master" it overwrites userImages folder.
I tried without userImages folder in my git repository but even this doesnt help. Looks like everytime you upload a new version of app every folder and file is rewritten. Now question is how can I retain this userImages folder?

Regards,
Chidan

Comment: guys, any one has an answer for my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku has a [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) and as far as I know, (and as much as I wish it weren't) I don't think you can get any files to persist.

However, heroku offers a free Postgres database per app, and anything in your database will persist. You'll have to use the node.js `pg` package to access Postgres.

Edit: I believe it's also possible to use S3 (which might work better for something like images). You'll have to look that up though.